# How to spawn new process everytime I call a recursive function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mergesort, spawn

I am trying to create a recursive function, say Merge Sort. I want to create a new process every time I call the function.

Basically I want to divide the task into two parts every time I call the function and pass each part to a new process.

Here is my code:

**merge.js**

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    var arr = chunk.trim().split(' ');

    mergeSort(arr,0,arr.length - 1); 
  // I want to create new threads like this
  // CreateNewLeftThread
  // CreateNewRightThread
  // Join(lefThread.rightThread)


    function mergeSort(arr,left,right) {

        if (left < right) {

            var mid = Math.floor(left + (right - left)/2);
            mergeSort(arr,left,mid);
            mergeSort(arr,mid+1,right);
            merge(arr,left,right,mid);

        }

    }

    function Merge(Parameters) {

        /*Code Here*/

    }

    process.exit(0);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need it?
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

There is an overhead for doing this.

> > These child Nodes are still whole new instances of V8. Assume at least 30ms startup and 10mb memory for each new Node. That is, you cannot create many thousands of them.

I would rather have some message queue or just a pool of child processes.
So every time you need to create a new process you just push a message with parameters to one of pool instances or into the queue.

And if your Merge function is quick enough there is no reason to have all of this stuff, straight forward calculation will do.

Comment: [link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/03-13/MergeSort.java).In this program, how easy it is to create a left thread,right thread and then just start them.I am looking for it to do in Node JS.Merge SOrt is just an example.I just want to learn the syntax to do it in Node JS.